# Return user data with Strapi and Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, strapi

I couldn't find similar questions so I had to ask this one. I think it's a pretty simple task but I can't figure out how to do it. I'm working with Strapi and Next.js to build an authentication system.

How can the client get the user data back from the server?

```
// login.js

const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    axios.post("/api/login", {
        identifier: `${credentials.email}`,
        password: `${credentials.password}`,
        remember: stayLoggedIn,
    })
    .then(()=> {
        // response.data.user
        Router.push("/")
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Error reaching /api/login ->", error)
    })
}
```

The client needs to get `response.data.user` back from the server.

```
// /api/login.js

export default (req, res) => {

const {identifier, password} = req.body;

// Strapi login
axios.post(`${API_URL}/api/auth/local`, {
    identifier, password
})
.then(response => {

    // Get user data from Strapi
    const jwt = response.data.jwt;
    console.log("Got token, trying login. Token: ", jwt)
    console.log(response.data.user)

    // set httponly cookie
    res.setHeader(
        "Set-Cookie",
        cookie.serialize("jwt", jwt, {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
            maxAge: 60 * 60,
            sameSite: "strict",
            path: "/",
        })
    )
    console.log("Login successful")
    res.status(200).end()
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log("Error logging in", error)
    res.status(400).end()
})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a route in Strapi `/api/users/me` that you should pass jwt in headers then it will return user data. **Note:** Always use this route as authenticate route.

```
   try {
      const request = await fetch(
       `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/users/me`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,//  when user login there will be a jwt in reponse so you can pass user jwt in here 
      },
    }
  );
  const response = await request.json();
  console.log(response);//{id : 1 ,email : 'abc@email.com' , username : "abc"}
  res.status(200).json(response);
} catch (err) {
  res.status(403).json({ msg: "Your are not loggedin" });
}
```

active the route from user-permissions -> check the **me**
[image]